# Fastest way to get elements in viewport

Tags: javascript, dom

I am dynamically creating a VERY large HTML file with as many elements as the browser on any given computer can feasibly generate.

I then need to, as the user scrolls, access the elements of a certain type (let's say div) that are actually within the viewport.

The only way I know how to get a list of the elements visible in the viewport is to loop through all elements and then see if their bounds overlap with the current viewport.  The problem with this is that there are so many elements in the document that this process can not complete quickly enough to let the browser scroll.

Is there a faster way to get all elements within the viewport?

Comment: are all of this elements in a list view?

Comment: have a look up this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: If you are generating parents nodes for large groups of nodes you could have a listener keep track of which parent is in the viewport (like http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) and then run a visibility check (like the one @marmeladze linked to) limited to children of that parent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Divide and conquer**

You can divide the area of the window in smaller areas (FNO blocks). If the website is mainly vertical, you don't need more than one column (block width equals document width). After you populate the page, add each node and its descendants to the blocks in which they reside (they can be in more than one block). On the scroll event handler you only need to check the nodes in the visible blocks. If the height of each block equals the height of the viewport, you will only need to check up to two blocks. **And no matter how big the page is, you always find the blocks as follows**:

```js
var from = Math.trunc( viewport.y / blockHeight ) ;
var to = Math.trunc( viewport.y2 / blockHeight ) ;
```

In the following example, I dynamically create 10,500 nodes; after that, you can scroll the page and the visible divs will be listed. You can adapt the function called matches if you want to filter the nodes differently. I tested this in my tablet with Chrome and 200,000 nodes, after the page was loaded, the scroll was smooth. The performance may drop when you add more nodes than the computer/browser can handle, the algorithm works fine. With the same test machine and 1,000,000 nodes the scrolling wasn't taking place in real time, but it wasn't that slow.

**Page loading will take time, please be patient.**

```js
var blocks = [] ;
var blockHeight ;
var blocksNumber ;
function isVisible( element, vp )
{
    /* This checks if the element is in the viewport area, you could also
     * check the display and visibility of its style.
     */
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect( ) ;
    var x = rect.left ;
    var x2 = x + element.offsetWidth ;
    var y = rect.top ;
    var y2 = y + element.offsetHeight ;
    return !( x >= vp.w || y >= vp.h || x2 < 0 || y2 < 0 ) ;
}
function matches( element, vp )
{
    /* You can filter the elements even further */
    return element && element.id && element.tagName === "DIV" && isVisible( element, vp ) ;
}
function viewport( )
{
    this.x = window.pageXOffset ;
    this.w = window.innerWidth ;
    this.x2 = this.x + this.w - 1 ;
    this.y = window.pageYOffset ;
    this.h = window.innerHeight ;
    this.y2 = this.y + this.h - 1 ;
    return this ;
}
function addMatch( element, array )
{
    /* An element may be in more than one block, so you need
     * to check if it wasn't already added.
     */
    for( var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; ++i )
    {
        if( array[i] === element ) return ;
    }
    array.push( element ) ;
}
function onWindowScroll( )
{
    var msg = document.getElementById( "msg" ) ;
    var str = "" ;

    var vp = new viewport( ) ;
    var from = Math.trunc( vp.y / blockHeight ) ;
    var to = Math.trunc( vp.y2 / blockHeight ) ;
    str += "Nodes: " + document.body.childNodes.length
         + ", blocks: " + blocks.length
         + ", searching blocks " + from + "-" + to + "<br>"
         + "Founded: " ;
    var array = [] ;
    for( var b = from ; b <= to ; ++b )
    {
        var block = blocks[b] ;
        for( var i = 0 ; i < block.length ; ++i )
        {
            if( matches( block[i], vp ) )
            {
                addMatch( block[i], array ) ;
            }
        }
    }
    if( array.length )
    {
        for( var i = 0 ; i < array.length-1 ; ++i )
        {
            str += array[i].id + " " ;
        }
        str += array[array.length-1].id ;
    }
    else
    {
        str += "none" ;
    }
    msg.innerHTML = str ;
}
function onWindowLoad( )
{
    setTimeout( function( )
    {
        var i = 0 ;
        /* Lets populate the page */
        while( i < 10000 )
        {
            var element = document.createElement( "DIV" ) ;
            element.className = "first" ;
            element.innerHTML = i ;
            element.id = i++ ;
            document.body.appendChild( element ) ;
            element = document.createElement( "SECOND" ) ;
            element.className = "second" ;
            element.innerHTML = i ;
            element.id = i++ ;
            document.body.appendChild( element ) ;
        }
        /* Lets add random positioned elements */
        var i = 0 ;
        while( i < 500 )
        {
            var x = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * document.body.offsetWidth ) ;
            var y = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * document.body.offsetHeight ) ;
            if( Math.random( ) < 0.5 )
            {
                var element = document.createElement( "DIV" ) ;
                element.className = "absolute-first" ;
            }
            else
            {
                var element = document.createElement( "SECOND" ) ;
                element.className = "absolute-second" ;
            }
            element.style.left = x + "px" ;
            element.style.top = y + "px" ;
            element.id = "r" + i++ ;
            element.innerHTML = element.id ;
            document.body.appendChild( element ) ;
        }
        /* Now we create the blocks */
        var nodes = document.body.childNodes ;
        blockHeight = window.innerHeight ;
        blocksNumber = Math.ceil( document.body.offsetHeight / blockHeight ) ;
        for( var b = 0 ; b < blocksNumber ; ++b )
        {
            blocks[b] = new Array( ) ;
        }
        /* And we add all the nodes into they corresponding blocks */
        for( var i = 0 ; i < nodes.length ; ++i )
        {
            addElement( nodes[i] ) ;
        }
        addEventListener( "scroll", onWindowScroll, false ) ;
        onWindowScroll( ) ; // Initialize msg
    }, 20 ) ;
}
function addElement( element )
{
    /* This works fine if the rest of the nodes stayed in the
     * same position with the same size when element was added.
     */
    if( !element.getBoundingClientRect ) return ;
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect( ) ;
    var y = rect.top + window.pageYOffset ;
    var y2 = y + element.offsetHeight ;
    var from = Math.trunc( y / blockHeight ) ;
    var to = Math.trunc( y2 / blockHeight ) ;
    for( var b = from ; b <= to ; ++b )
    {
        blocks[b].push( element ) ;
    }
    var nodes = element.childNodes ;
    if( nodes )
    {
        for( var i = 0 ; i < nodes.length ; ++i )
        {
            addElement( nodes[i] ) ;
        }
    }
}
function removeElement( element )
{
    /* This works fine if the rest of the nodes stayed in the
     * same position with the same size when element was added.
     */
    if( !element.getBoundingClientRect ) return ;
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect( ) ;
    var y = rect.top + window.pageYOffset ;
    var y2 = y + element.offsetHeight ;
    var from = Math.trunc( y / blockHeight ) ;
    var to = Math.trunc( y2 / blockHeight ) ;
    for( var b = from ; b <= to ; ++b )
    {
        var i = blocks[b].indexOf( element ) ;
        if( i > -1 )
        {
            blocks[b].splice( i, 1 ) ;
        }
    }
}
addEventListener( "load", onWindowLoad, false ) ;
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0 auto ;
    text-align: center ;
    font-family: sans-serif ;
}
/* Filtered in elements are light green */
.first
{
    height: 50px ;
    line-height: 50px ;
    background-color: #cfc ;
}
/* Filtered out elements are light red */
.second
{
    display: block ;
    height: 30px ;
    line-height: 30px ;
    background-color: #fcc ;
    box-sizing: border-box ;
}
/* Filtered in elements are light green */
.absolute-first
{
    background-color: #cfc ;
}
/* Filtered out elements are light red */
.absolute-second
{
    background-color: #fcc ;
}
.absolute-first, .absolute-second
{
    position: absolute ;
    padding: 1pt 5pt 1pt 5pt ;
}
.first, .second, .absolute-first, .absolute-second
{
    border: 1px solid #444 ;
}
#msg
{
    position: fixed ;
    z-index: 1 ;
    top: 0 ;
    left: 0 ;
    width: 100% ;
    min-height: 24pt ;
    line-height: 24pt ;
    border: 1px solid #000 ;
    background-color: #ffd ;
    box-sizing: border-box ;
    font-size: 14pt ;
    vertical-align: middle ;
    text-align: left ;
    padding-left: 3pt ;
    opacity: 0.7 ;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    <div id="a1">
        <div id="a11" class="first">a11</div>
        <div id="a12" class="first">a12</div>
    </div>
    <div id="a2" class="first">a2</div>
</div>
<msg id="msg">Loading page, please wait...</msg>
```

The only disadvantage is that you have to keep the nodes in their corresponding blocks. The blocks should be updated when you add a new node, when you remove an existing node or when a node is moved or resized. This should not be a problem as you said that you first populate the page.

> The fixed positioned nodes are not taken into account. It is easy to add support for them, but it would add nothing valuable to the example.